# How can I touch up a marred furniture paint job?

Tags: painting, furniture

I recently repainted some night stands using benjamin moore advanced paint. They look great, except that I noticed some debris on the top and removed it with tweezers. I attempted to smooth over it with a brush, but the paint had already started to dry. So, there's a slight mar to my finish in a few places. Can I lightly sand that area, and just put a very light coat on top? Or, am I stuck with a light sand and repainting the entire top?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't say how large the entire top was. Over brush snagging looks terrible, unfortunately. If you really want a smooth consistant finish, don't attempt to just touch up the flaw areas. I would sand the top again, making sure the snags are very smooth, then put a thin coat on the entire top. Dust control is the key to doing furniture. If there is minor dust on the finish, leave it alone until the piece is cured completely. You can then buff if with a polish compound or ultra fine automotive finishing paper that won't scratch the gloss, but will remove minor dust flaws.

Comment: +1 to refinishing and dust  The BM Advance paint is a new, water based alkyd.  As such, its drying (and leveling) time is extended, compared to latex.  Much harder film when dry.  If, after your sanding is complete and you didn't break through to wood or primer, you can top coat with a water based poly of the same sheen.  These dry quicker than the alkyds.  Light sanding @600 grit between coats will net you a very smooth surface.  Try turning off furnace during the initial dry if you recoat with the Advance.

Comment: @HerrBag - I just tried the advance, this is my first attempt at painting furniture. I had originally tried the Behr Ultra Premium, and it looked awful, even after multiple coats. Thanks for the tips

Comment: @shirlockhomes - can you recommend a polish compound or finishing paper? Thanks for the detailed answer

Comment: Dupont auto paste polishing compound, or 3M 1200 or finer auto paper. You should find either at an auto supply store. the paste is common even at WalMart.